# Spring DataSource: EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder addScript() throws FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm using Spring-Boot and an in-memory H2 database. I'm trying to configure the database through a configuration class by using a DataSource Bean.
I want that when the application starts a script is execuded which inserts some rows in my database.
Therefore I use the method `addScript()` of the `EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder`. But I continue to get FileNotFoundExceptions.

The Entity is correct and the correct table is created which I can check with the h2-console. Also the file import.sql does exist in the correct folder. Intellij does find this file.

The `import.sql`file:

```
INSERT INTO USER (id, user_name, password, first_name, last_name, email) VALUES
(0,'test','12345','Test','Entry','example@mail.com'),
```

```java
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
       return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript("db/sql/import.sql")
                .build();
    }

}
```

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [db/sql/import.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I would like that the sql statement is properly executed on the application start.

Comment: Those scripts should be added to your resources folder.

Answer (score 1):

Your files should go in resources folder. The hierarchy should look like this:

```
src    
├───main
│   ├───java
│   │   └───com
│   │       └───YourCode
│   │           │   Application.java
│   │           └───config
│   │                   DataSourceConfig.java
│   └───resources   
│       └───db   
│           └───sql
│               import.sql         
└───test
    └───java
```